# Windows 8 continues to ask for password after restart

Tags: windows-8, passwords

I have continually adjusted the windows settings so that when I turn on/restart my computer, it does not ask me for a password.  I have windows 8.  When I access the "run" window by right clicking my start menu icon, follow the netplwiz commands etc.  the "user must enter a user name and password..." box is unchecked.  I am the only user on my computer but when I restart it, it brings me to the "other user" window where a message reads as follows: “The user name or password is incorrect.  Try again.” This happens like clockwork every time I turn off or restart my computer.  I have to hit escape where it takes me the “other user” window where I can enter a user name and password.  I have to hit the back arrow “switch user” to get to my account.  Under this window, my email address is saved but it STILL asks for my password.  HELP.

Comment: have you tried the linked tool?

Answer (score 0):

I always use the program [autologon.exe from sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/autologon.aspx). Run it as admin, type in your data and select `Enable`.

[image]

This works fine in Windows 8.